# Different approach to finding possible values of slope of line intersecting a given circle

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems, secant

Given an equation of circle
$(x-3)^2+(y+2)^2=25$ . A line $y=mx+1$ intesects the circle at points $P$ and $Q$ such that $x$ coordinate of the midpoint of $PQ$ is $\frac{-3}{5}.$

We have to find range of $m.$
Given answer is $m \in[2,4).$

**My approach**:

I did find out the $y$ coordinate by putting $x$ is given equation of line. Then since the line $PQ$ will be perpendicular to the line joining the point $(3,-2)$ and midpoint of line segment $PQ.$
Finally I equated the product of two slopes to $-1$ and hence solved the quadratic obtained in $m$ and got the possible values of $m.$

**WHAT I WANT TO ASK**:

Since the line intersects the circle in two points, I substituted $y=mx+1$ in circle and got quadratic equation in $x$ with coffiecients in terms of $m.$
Since I know that the line intersects in two real points I put the condition that discriminant of the quadratic  obtained is greater than $0,$ but the quadratic obtained has non-real roots.
I want to ask what is wrong in the second approach ?

Comment: Do you mean "midpoint of $PQ$ has $x$-coordinate $\displaystyle\frac{-3}{5}$"?

Comment: Yes midpoint of PQ is (-3/5) X coordinate , y is not given in question

Comment: First edit your question to avoid confusion for other users. Also, you can use MathJax in comments, too.

Comment: You you like to accept the answer? :-)

Answer (score 1):

The second approach will give
$$x^2(m^2+1)+x(6m-6)-7=0.$$
Discriminant $D=64m^2-72m+64$ is positive for all  $m\in \mathbb{R}.$

This signifies that for each $m,$ the line will cut the circle at two distinct points.
It is logical because all the lines pass through the point $(0,1)$ which lies inside the circle.

Let us continue.
The midpoint is arithmetic mean of $P$ and $Q.$  For $x$-coordinates that we know, we solve
$$\frac{-6m+6}{2(m^2+1)}=-\frac{3}{5}$$ or equivalently
$$m^2-5m+6=0.$$

(Is the given answer correct?)

Comment: Yes , thanks for clarification .

Comment: @User376343, but the equation gives only two distinct values.

Comment: Apparently, you're right. It seems I was far from being concentrated :)

Answer (score 0):

The lines you are considering pass through the point $(0,1)$ which is an interior point for the circle.  So every line intersects the circle in two distinct points.

It seems that your first line of reasoning is not quite correct, but the second is.

Comment: But when second quadratic is obtained by putting line in equation of circle , then comparing the coffiecient of sum of roots of the equation that is 2(-3/5) as (X1+X2)/2=-3/5 considered X1 and X2 are coordinate of P and Q , then the answer is true

Answer (score 0):

Just to verify the answer given by @user376343 is correct. There will be only two discrete values of $m,\ 2\ \text{or}\ 3$ rather than a range of values. [image]